# Was very little or no new medication developed in the USSR?

Tags: medical-science, russia, medications, pharmaceutical, soviet-union

Prof. Robert (Haim) Belmaker, head of the [Israeli Psychiatric Association](https://psychiatry.doctorsonly.co.il/), [spoke today](http://www.kan.org.il/Radio/item.aspx?pid=22342) (2018-01-05) on the סדר יום / *Daily Agenda* radio program (Note this is a program in Hebrew).

At some point in the conversation he claimed that "during the USSR's 70 years of existence, no new תרופה [i.e. cure/medication] was developed".

Now, ignoring the Socialism-vs-Capitalism debate (and the nature of the USSR) - is it indeed the case that no medication or medicinal drugs or compounds were developed in the USSR?

Note: I'm asking about "pharmacological" developments, not other kinds of treatments like exercises or surgical procedures and so on.

Comment: Can you please confirm that the word "תרופה" specifically refers medications, and not medicine as a whole? i.e. that the claim is focussed only on one limited aspect of treatment  and that an answer showing the progress that the Soviet Union made in getting basic healthcare and sanitation practices out to the people doesn't count.

Comment: @Oddthinking: Confirmed.

Comment: If he is part of the Psychiatric association, is it possible he's talking specifically about psychiatric medicine etc.?

Comment: @Orangesandlemons: Unlikely, he was explaining how "Socialism is much worse than Capitalism" generally. Although the question still stands regardless.

Comment: I am surprised by the answer as I know Russian industry is very antiquated. Twenty years ago I audited steel mills there . They still used the 100 year old Pilger method to make seamless pipe . To add insult to injury some of the equipment in service had been taken from Germany after WW2. This is not reflective of Russian engineers but of the government system.

Comment: @blacksmith37: Even if  some Russian industry may be antiquated, surely not all of it was. After all, the USSR built advanced aircraft which could  match the USA's, or come close to it depending on the circumstances; it launched spaceships and submarines and so on - those are consistent advances in industrial capabilities. So it couldn't all have been 100-year-old tech.

Comment: They are/were good with war equipment.Saw a number of Ural motorcycles . they were mostly on the side of the road, stalled. The road from Yekaterinburg to Chelyabinsk  ( a situation like Chicago to St Louis ) , 2 lane and so rough I had to brace myself  against the roof of the Ford Van ( USSR couldn't make vans) at about 50 MPH .  I have a million stories.

Comment: @einpoklum I'm sure part of the reason they built such good war equipment was because it was hard to acquire to copy. The history of Russian computer science is boring, because instead of designing their own things, they cloned American computers, like the VAX, and used Western languages, like ALGOL-68 and Ada. Instead of Russian medical research, it seems quite probable they spent more time cloning Western medical research.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Concerning the claim in the question headline: it might be difficult to properly define "very little", compare that to Western medicine. Then start an argument about what counts statistically as…

Thankfully such [claimants](https://mises.org/library/what-soviet-medicine-teaches-us) are inclined to use the absolute.

> "during the USSR's 70 years of existence, **no new** תרופה [i.e. cure/medication] was developed".

<sup>(Emphasis mine.)</sup>

A single counter example is sufficient to disprove this claim.

> [Phenazepam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenazepam)
>   Phenazepam (also known in Russia as bromdihydrochlorphenylbenzodiazepine) is a benzodiazepine drug, which was developed in the Soviet Union in 1975

But why stop there?

> [**D. B.Jackand & N.P.Mason: "The Pharmaceutical Industry in the U.S.S.R.", Journal of Clinical Pharmacy and Therapeutics (1987) 12,401-407**](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2710.1987.tb00553.x/pdf)
>   It would be a mistake, however, to give the impression that there is nothing new to say about the Soviet pharmaceutical industry. […]  In October, 1985, The
>   Times reported the recent discovery by Soviet scientists of a polymer, Feracryl, designed to replace oil in tempering processes, that proved to be a very potent haemostatic agent. Very few side-effects were observed. […]

Further examples from drugs developed in the USSR:

[Gramicidin S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramicidin_S) – [Bromantane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromantane) – [Corvalol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corvalol) – [Feprosidnine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feprosidnine) – [Fluacizine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluacizine) – [Gidazepam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gidazepam) – [Latrepirdine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latrepirdine) – [Meldonium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meldonium) – [Mesocarb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesocarb) – [Phenazepam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenazepam) – [Phenibut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenibut) – [Phenylpiracetam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenylpiracetam) – [Picamilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picamilon) – [Pipofezine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipofezine) – [Sulfozinum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfozinum) – [Arabinopyranosyl-N-methyl-N-nitrosourea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabinopyranosyl-N-methyl-N-nitrosourea) – [Anthrax vaccines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthrax_vaccines)

Some of these have very interesting cultural characteristics:

> Mesocarb (brand names Sidnocarb, Sydnocarb) is a stimulant drug which was developed in the USSR in the 1970s. […] Mesocarb is almost unknown in the western world and is neither used in medicine or studied scientifically to any great extent outside Russia and other countries in the former Soviet Union. It has however been added to the list of drugs under international control and is illegal in most countries, despite its multiple therapeutic applications and reported lack of significant abuse potential.
>   (Cited from the above Wikipedia article.)

Before the seventies the general outlook of contemporary competitors was the exact opposite of the current wholesale dismissal:

> ["The Pharmaceutical Century – Ten Decades of Drug Discovery"](http://www3.uah.es/farmamol/The%20Pharmaceutical%20Century/Ch4.html): The perceived “science gap” between the United States and the Soviet Union led to the 1958 National Defense Education Act.

Just some general hints from Wikipedia:

[Luka (Voyno-Yasenetsky)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luka_(Voyno-Yasenetsky))
[Nikolai Kravkov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikolai_Kravkov)
[Gavriil Ilizarov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gavriil_Ilizarov)
[Alexander A. Maximow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_A._Maximow)
[Gene pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_pool)
[Kidney transplantation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kidney_transplantation)
[Acoustic microscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_microscopy)
[Vladimir Demikhov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Demikhov)
[Modern synthesis (20th century)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_synthesis_(20th_century))
[Theodosius Dobzhansky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodosius_Dobzhansky)
[Phage therapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phage_therapy) 
[Georgy Gause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgy_Gause)
[Electron paramagnetic resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_paramagnetic_resonance)
[Heart–lung transplant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart%E2%80%93lung_transplant)
[Vladimir Demikhov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Demikhov)
[Lung transplantation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lung_transplantation)
[Belousov–Zhabotinsky reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belousov%E2%80%93Zhabotinsky_reaction)
[Anthropometric cosmetology](http://Anthropometric_cosmetology)
[Ilizarov apparatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilizarov_apparatus)
[Radial keratotomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_keratotomy)
[Svyatoslav Fyodorov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svyatoslav_Fyodorov)

Comment: +1, but I specifically asked about pharmacological developments, while you seem to have listed surgey procedure developments, diagnostic methods etc. so the long list is only partially relevant.

Comment: Bacteriophage Research could sneak in here too

Comment: What does Belousov–Zhabotinsky have to do with pharma?

Comment: Or Ilizarov (I guess = Илизаров) mentioned twice? He did not invent any new medicine. He was an excellent doctor and invented very important ways to treat people with leg traumas (this is used a lot outside of Russia now, in particular in Israel). In the USSR it was used in exactly one place: Ilizarov's Institute.